Shub Conjecture and polynomial entropy
The  Shub conjecture on topological entropy $h(f)$ of  self  map f on  manifold M says that the  topological entropy is  greater (or equal) than (to) the log of  maximum absolute values of the  eigenvalues of  the  linear map $f_*$ induced on Homologies.
Are there some Polynomial  entropy  version of this conjecture  on compact topological manifolds or  even topological space?
The  polynomial  entropy is described here
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S156035472304007X
I  asked the  question in Physicsoverflow and   in a  comment  form in RG too.

You would replace the exponential growth rate for the action on the homology by the new growth rate: look at the limits of  $|f_^n|/\log n$. But it is only of interest if the spectrum of $f_$ is contained in the imaginary axis.

@JohnB Thank you!  are there some  dynamical interpretations for this spectrum condition?

@JohnB Please expand your  comment

@JohnB  are there examples of  non vanishing of the  induced homology map $f_*$ but the  topological entropy $h(f)=0$?

@JohnB  BTW in the  question I did not say that we  formally replace topological entropy with polynomial one(without any other possible change). I  would  appreciate if  you read my question again

There is nothing to expand in my comment, sorry, it is only my answer to your question "Are there ..." I have never seen it written anywhere and yes, of course, $\log n$ can be replaced by any other rate. Is this interesting? Maybe, probably not (but if so it could perhaps help understanding the dynamics of zero entropy maps). It is doubtful for example that Yomdin's proof for $C^\infty$ maps extends to other growth rates (sorry, too technical to explain here why).

@JohnB  As you pointed out, my motivation for this question was just zero entropy  maps
